# Azure web sites disappeared

Tags: azure

I have two free Azure websites working for some months, but today they both have disappeared from the portal and are not working. I cannot create new ones with the same urls, because those names are considered incorrect now. I'm trying to enter application service blade to find out something, but portal just showing infinite loading indicator. All other resources on this plan are present and working fine. How can I bring those apps to live again with same urls?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a transient error, related to a temporary service outage. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an ongoing issue with the European data centers: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Comment: You are right, looks like there were some issues, but now I see my apps are back, so maybe it is fixed.

Comment: FYI the question itself should be closed, as it's not programming-related and it's a transient issue. This type of response really should be a comment, not an answer.